# Should I use the word successfully in pop-up messages?

Tags: error-message, copywriting, popup, messagebox

The workflow:

User clicks on a button that triggers some action. On top of the screen appears a small pop-up that informs about the result of an action (successful or not).

*For example:*

**New files added successfully**

**New files weren't added**

---

**Files deleted successfully**

**Files weren't deleted**

---

**Users invited successfully**

**Users weren't invited**

---

Should I use successfully each time? Or just for short sentences denoting small actions?

Comment: Why are you using the word "successfully" anyway? Your pop-up already suggests that an action has been executed. For that matter, you could just say "New files were added" and "New files weren't added"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need it; the action has already been confirmed.

Generally speaking a good rule is that if you can remove a word and the message still conveys the same message then remove it and in this case, that stands true.

Comment: That's a good rule no matter what you're writing.